# Interpreting rawPrediction from Spark ML LinearSVC

Tags: svm, apache-spark

I am using Spark ML's LinearSVC in a binary classification model. The `transform` method creates two columns, `prediction` and `rawPrediction`. Spark's docs don't provide any way of interpreting the `rawPrediction` column for this particular classifier. This question has been asked and answered for other classifiers, but not specifically for LinearSVC.

For a binary classification problem, the LinearSVC column contains pairs of values that range well below 0 and well above 1. Clearly this isn't simply the probability of belonging to each class. What is it?

Here's a model built on a subset of features in the original dataset. Fitting any data with Spark's LinearSVC will produce this column.

```
var df = sqlContext
  .read
  .format("csv")
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("inferSchema", "true")
  .load("/FileStore/tables/full_frame_20180716.csv")


var assembler = new VectorAssembler()
  .setInputCols(Array("oy_length", "ah_length", "ey_length", "vay_length", "oh_length", "longest_word_length", "total_words", "repeated_exact_words", "repeated_bigrams", "repeated_lemmatized_words", "repeated_lemma_bigrams"))
  .setOutputCol("features")

df = assembler.transform(df)

var Array(train, test) = df.randomSplit(Array(.8,.2), 42)

var supvec = new LinearSVC()
  .setLabelCol("written_before_2004")
  .setMaxIter(10)
  .setRegParam(0.001)

var supvecModel = supvec.fit(train)

var predictions = supvecModel.transform(test)

predictions.select("rawPrediction").show(20, false)
```

Output:

```
+----------------------------------------+ 
|rawPrediction | 
+----------------------------------------+ 
|[1.1502868455791242,-1.1502868455791242]| 
|[0.853488887006264,-0.853488887006264] | 
|[0.8064994501574174,-0.8064994501574174]| 
|[0.7919862003563363,-0.7919862003563363]| 
|[0.847418035176922,-0.847418035176922] | 
|[0.9157433788236442,-0.9157433788236442]| 
|[1.6290888181913814,-1.6290888181913814]| 
|[0.9402461917731906,-0.9402461917731906]| 
|[0.9744052798627367,-0.9744052798627367]| 
|[0.787542624053347,-0.787542624053347] | 
|[0.8750602657901001,-0.8750602657901001]| 
|[0.7949414037722276,-0.7949414037722276]| 
|[0.9163545832998052,-0.9163545832998052]| 
|[0.9875454213431247,-0.9875454213431247]| 
|[0.9193015302646135,-0.9193015302646135]| 
|[0.9828623328048487,-0.9828623328048487]| 
|[0.9175976004208621,-0.9175976004208621]| 
|[0.9608750388820302,-0.9608750388820302]| 
|[1.029326217566756,-1.029326217566756] | 
|[1.0190290910146256,-1.0190290910146256]| 
+----------------------------------------+ 

only showing top 20 rows
```